# How to store all including repeating(non-unique) object in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, mongoose

I want to store and display all(including repeated) objects but it only stores distinct(unique) values.

The **good thing** is *total* is adding all the values **including reoccurring**
The **Bad thing** is *indistinctresult* **cannot store reoccurring object**
**for** loop also **does not work**

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    User.find({ _id: req.user._id }, function (err, cartitem) {
      var noofcartitem = cartitem[0].cart_array.length;

      product.find({ _id: cartitem[0].cart_array }, function (err, result) {
        var total = 0;
        var x;
        var indistinctresult = [];  ***//stores only distinct(Unique) values*** 
        for (x in result) {
          total += result[x].price;
          indistinctresult.push(result[x]);
        }
        console.log(indistinctresult); **//expected to log all(including non unique) values**
        res.render("cart", {
          cart_array: noofcartitem,
          total: total,
          cartproduct: indistinctresult,
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: What does this line do: `for (x in result) { ... }`? `x` is not assigned a value anywhere in your code.

Comment: x loop to the number of items in result.

Comment: First step, replace `for (x in result)` with `for (let x=0; x<result.length; x++)` then tell us what happens

Comment: same result sir, the problem is  indistinctresult stores only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using **for..in**  loop for iterating through array. It's not a good idea.

The following link might be helpful to you.

[Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: can you please suggest me the way I can get my job done because i tried for loop the problem was that i cannot acess the variable out of loop.

Comment: the result is too long.

Comment: I think your query result itself contains only unique values. Then how you are expecting indistinct values? How you are defining your unique items?

Comment: no,total variable is adding reoccurring values and on logging the result inside loop is also printing reoccuring object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 1]
const y = []
for (let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    y.push(x[i]);  
}
console.log(y);
```

OUTPUT: [1, 2, 3, 1]
Replace you `for..in` loop with `for` loop with index.